# Insert Excel rows for each x in adjacent country columns to prepare Oracle Calendar Event Coverage uploadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, oracle-fusion-apps

I am uploading Calendar Events in Oracle Fusion. The events went fine, but I am now working on assigning the coverage which is set by country in our setup.

My coverage source data (this is sample of it), delivered by a colleagues is structured as:

| Short Code2 | Name2 | NL | DE | GB | FR | LU | ES | AU | CA | CL | US | FI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NYD1-23 | New Year's Day 2023 | x | x |  | x | x | x |  |  |  |  | x |
| NYD2-23 | New Year's Holiday 2023 |  |  | x |  |  |  | x | x | x | x |  |
| EP-23 | Epiphany 2023 |  |  |  |  |  | x |  |  |  |  | x |
| MLK-23 | Martin Luther King Day 2023 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | x |  |
| ADH-23 | Australia Day Holiday 2023 |  |  |  |  |  |  | x |  |  |  |  |
| LB-23 | Lincoln's Birthday 2023 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | x |  |
| PRES-23 | Presidents' Day 2023 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | x |  |
| ADH-23 | Family Day 2023 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | x |  |  |  |
| STJ-23 | Saint Josephs day 2023 |  |  |  |  |  | x |  |  |  |  |  |
| EAT-23 | Easter Thursday 2023 |  |  |  |  |  | x |  |  |  |  |  |

I could alter the data, to include helper columns or anything that would make the task easier.

What Oracle needs in the uploadsheet for coverage is the following format:

| Short Code | Coverage Node | Coverage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NYD1-23 | NL | I |
| NYD1-23 | DE | I |
| NYD1-23 | FR | I |
| NYD1-23 | LU | I |
| NYD1-23 | ES | I |
| NYD1-23 | FI | I |
| NYD2-23 | GB | I |
| NYD2-23 | AU | I |
| NYD2-23 | CA | I |
| NYD2-23 | CL | I |
| NYD2-23 | US | I |

etc.

So the Short Code needs to be repeated on each row, for the amount of x's that are on the row. The country codes need to each be on a separate row and the third column is always I (for include).

So far, I've been wrecking my brain with MOD, ARRAY, TRANSPOSE and FILTER functions in Excel but I think I'm going about it the wrong way. There must be an easier solution that I am not seeing.

I'm using Excel on 365. (Version 2202 Build 16.0.14931.20858)

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your data via [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation). It makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: Updated the tables to the markdown format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a table (insert > table) from your data and called it "data".

You can use this formula:

```vb
=LET(cntCountries,COLUMNS(data),
cntRows, ROWS(data)*cntCountries,

shortCodeByRowλ,LAMBDA(r,INT((r-1)/cntCountries)+1),
countryCodesByRowλ,LAMBDA(r,MOD(r-1,cntCountries)+1),

shortcodes,MAKEARRAY(cntRows,1,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(data[Short Code2],shortCodeByRowλ(r)))),
countrycodes,MAKEARRAY(cntRows,1,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(data[#Headers],1,countryCodesByRowλ(r)))),
selection,SUBSTITUTE(MAKEARRAY(cntRows,1,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(data,shortCodeByRowλ(r),countryCodesByRowλ(r)) )),"x","I"),

FILTER(HSTACK(shortcodes,countrycodes,selection),selection="I"))
```

The basic idea is to create each column based on MAKEARRAY.
The values are each retrieved based on the row of the new array - either from the short code column or from the header country codes. --> using the two LAMBDA-functions.

for the result the HSTACKEd array is filter for the I rows.

There are two lambdas to retrieve either the short code or the country code for the row.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ike, thanks a lot for taking the time to answer.
I have been trying to get results in the way that you do, but I just couldn't get there. Looks like a good solution.

Changed my table name to 'data', but I am getting an error when I try to input your formula. Excel's compiler sends me to the first 'r' on the third row. It doesn't seem to recognize the LAMBDA formula.

Comment: Then you don't have the current channel of Excel 365 and can't use the LAMBDA-function :-( (Most likely you don't have HSTACK as well ...) You could replace the individual Lambda calls by the formula - but it will get pretty messy then.

Comment: You are correct. Also don't have the HSTACK function. I will see if I can hack together the formulas for the three columns separately.
Want to thank you for pushing me in the right direction. Will mark it as answer when I have completed the task.

Comment: Hey Ike, just wanted to let you know that I now have the LAMBDA function available and was able to use your script for the 2024 run. Thanks again!